# Can I change the Exception's message language to other language?

Tags: python, django

Can I change the Exception's message language to Chinese?

```
try:
    new_project = admin_conn.conn.identity.create_project(**project_params)  # create_project

    print (new_project, new_project.id, "new project created")
except Exception as e:
    print (e.message)
    render(request, '/register/', {"errors": e.message.encode('utf-8')})
```

The `e.message.encode('utf-8')` is english, how can change it to Chinese?

---

**EDIT**

Because the Exception's message have many type errors, I can not transform every one, so in the django whether there is other convenient methods to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use `internationalization package` **i18n**

and then put your content b/w `{% trans %}` tag.

Make sure in **projects settings.py**

```
USE_I18N = True
```

**in html**

```
{% load i18n %}

{% trans "Successfully landed on this page" %}
```

If you have `message` variable.

```
{% trans {{message}} %}
```

And **don't foget** to add `chineese` as your language in html.

Comment: Can you provide more detail information about how to realize it?

Comment: @244boy, If the solution helped you, please select the answer, if any problem let me know. Thanks  for all the cooperation.